# How do I configure my Apache Alias directive to capture all paths except two?

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, redirect, alias

I'm using Apache 2 on Linux 18.04 with Python 3.6.  I have the following virtual host set up ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName lab.chicommons.coop

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias / /var/www/html/client/build/
        #<Directory /srv/rdmo/rdmo-app/static_root/>
        #    Require all granted
        #</Directory>
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        WSGIDaemonProcess maps \
            home=/var/www/html/web python-home=/var/www/html/web/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup maps 
        WSGIScriptAlias /coops /var/www/html/web/maps/wsgi.py/coops process-group=maps
        WSGIScriptAlias /data /var/www/html/web/maps/wsgi.py/data process-group=maps
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        <Directory /var/www/html/web/maps>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, this directive

```
Alias / /var/www/html/client/build/
```

captures all paths.  However, I would like to set it up such that it captures all paths except "/coops*" and "/data*".  How would I configure my Alias such that this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would get unruly with many more exceptions, but you can use PCRE's negative lookaheads easily here inside AliasMatch:

```
AliasMatch ^/(?!coops/)(?!data/).* /var/www/html/client/build/$0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Django's urls with regex to "catch" the urls. Define a url for "/coops*", a url for "/data*", and then a default url for anything else. If you want the web server to serve files directly from specific urls and not from Django, define them in `<Directory...>`.

Configure Apache according to this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). For example:

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

If you have urls which you want to run specific views, define them as `urlpatterns` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)). And then, define a default view which you define as the last urlpattern to "catch" any url which was not caught by a specific view, and allocate it to a default view. You can also redirect it to a specific view, for example the main page. Or, you can keep your website without a default view, and then any url which doesn't match any view will return 404, which you can also customize if you want to.

Comment: Could you demonstrate the configuraiton as it pertains to my question?